# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable, deploying ml model

Tags: python, html, machine-learning, flask

I am trying to take integer input values in 29 fields on HTML page and pass it to ML model as shown in python code above. I am getting an error 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable' this is probably due to values not getting passed correctly from HTML to python code. Below is python and html code. Thanks in advance !

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pickle
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import cgi

app = Flask(__name__)
cv = pickle.load(open("model/bc_model.pkl","rb"))

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    values = form.getvalue('values[]')
    array = []
    for value in values:
        array.append([value])
    prediction=cv.predict(array)
    return render_template("index.html",prediction=prediction)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080, debug=True)
```

```
<h1>Breast Cancer predictor</h1>
    <form method="post" action="/predict">
        <input type="number" name="values[]"><br>
        <input type="number" name="values[]"><br>
        <input type="number" name="values[]"><br>
         .....
         .....
        <input type="number" name="values[]"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
<div>
    <p id="display">{{prediction}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide the complete traceback

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to deploy a ML model on a web page through github codespace. HTML and python code snip is provided above. When I enter all 29 numeric values on HTML form and click submit I want result from ML model (which is built to predict Breast Cancer based on those 29 input values)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): (1/2)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1488, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1466, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1463, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 872, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

Comment: (2/2) File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 870, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()

  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.12/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 855, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
           
  File "/workspaces/bc_model/app.py", line 19, in predict
    for value in values:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable